# Suffixes in "grandiose" and "grandeur"

Tags: suffixes

"grand-" means "big". 
"grandiose" and "grandeur" have different meanings. So I would like to know what their suffixes "-iose" and "-eur" mean respectively?

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ose
http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-eur

Comment: If etymonline doesn't mention something, does it necessarily not exist?

Comment: Seems you are asking dictionary questions today :)

Comment: How does "-eur" mean "agent" of verb "grand"? "grand" isn't a verb.

Comment: abstract nouns from adjectives

Comment: Do you have more examples?

Comment: Both suffixes sound quintessential French. Do some background research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*-eur* is not really an English suffix; I believe it occurs only in loanwords from French. French has two suffixes *-eur*; the relevant one forms feminine nouns meaning "the property of being ___" from adjectives meaning "___", such as *grandeur* ("the property of being *grand*, big") and *froideur* ("the property of being *froid*, cold"). (The other one forms masculine agent nouns, such as *empereur* = "emperor", *acteur* = "actor"; that's the one found in English borrowings like *voyeur* and *connoisseur* (though in French the latter is now spelled *connaisseur*).)

*-ose* is not very common in English, either, but it's a bit less restricted; it's found in *otiose*, *bellicose*, *morose*, *adipose*, and so on, and it's basically just an adjective ending like *-ous*. (There's also another sense of *-ose*, which is more of an English suffix, and forms names of sugars: *sucrose*, *glucose*, *dextrose*, *lactose*, and so on.)

Comment: +1 However, the chemical suffix is not related to or relevant here.

Comment: @Kris: Re: chemical suffix: Yes, absolutely. My goal in mentioning it was actually to make clear that it's *not* related; from your comment, it seems that I failed in that goal. Do you have any thoughts how to fix that?